# We want no further [interaction] with this tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request

The [interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interaction) tag has 572 questions (and counting) and no tag wiki. Uses span the following areas:

- Many (probably a slim majority) have to do with [building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569736/define-peak-at-three-way-non-linear-interaction) [statistical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580267/how-to-make-all-interactions-before-using-glmnet) [models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395147/best-way-to-plot-interaction-effects-from-a-linear-model), and are really referring to **variable interaction**, or the third term in a formula like y = a + b + (a*b) This is the context in which I first wanted to use the tag.
- Several have to do with user interactions with an app, often in terms of [maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622980/how-to-customize-touch-interaction-on-leaflet-maps) or [other media](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311268/why-doesnt-my-uiimageview-respond-to-taps).
- The rest are more blatantly [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), having to do with the interaction of [programs with one another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044052/how-can-java-programs-in-different-jvms-affect-each-other-unintendedly) or [completely abstract concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575865/great-first-run-experience).

The burnination criteria:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   It describes the contents on a meta level but is not unambiguous. Many of the top-rated questions with [interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interaction) are completely unrelated to one another in terms of technology, language, context, desired effect, etc.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Yes; most uses are valid programming questions, often concerning either statistical software or user interfaces.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   It might if it were [variable-interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-interaction), at least to the modeling questions, as this is a common consideration when building models. Even then it is broad and in no case would it help you find a particular kind of question.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   As it's being used on the site, certainly not.

The questions about statistical modeling should be given a new tag, [variable-interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-interaction). Many questions would have the tag, it is something one can be an expert on, and it is much easier to search for and define use cases for.

So it's about a half-retag half-burninate job, by my estimate. What do you think?

### Update

In light of comments, I agree that there are drawbacks to a [variable-interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-interaction) tag, and this may be an opportunity for a larger discussion of how a community of machine-learning programmers straddles this site and [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Honestly, I'm not too keen on a _variable-interaction_ tag for statistical interaction, since there are lots of models that can account for interaction or express interaction in lots of different ways, and statistical interaction per sé doesn't narrow the topic of the question down by that much (the type of analysis/model narrows it down much more). Also, depending on the question, it might belong on [stats.se]

Comment: Point well taken. I still think it would be a valuable thing to search. Your comment applies to questions with the [tag:modeling] tag too, among others, but I personally find that to be useful.

Comment: Rather than [tag:variable-interaction], we should probably just retag those questions to [tag:statistics]. Since this site isn't strongly associated with statistics, it doesn't make sense to break that down into fine grained categories. Although *maybe* a [tag:statistical-modeling] tag would be justified, if that's sufficiently narrow within statistics.

Comment: @jpmc26 I think that's a sensible approach

Comment: Yeah, this should be burned - it's a bad tag.